# I am not able to set the Global variable in the following code. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, variables

Here is the issue: I am trying check and uncheck the check boxes by a group.

So if you select G1 and  G2, it throws a message that you cant mix groups. **If you uncheck all of them, i am trying to clear the existing grouping and that is where the code seems to fail.**

Any thoughts? (also,i might be having a wrong idea about that global var at the beginning. so please suggest)

```
<HTML>
<script language="javascript">
var prodSel="";
function VerifyGroup(a,b)
    {
    ClearAllSelectionsA(); // check if this is the last unselect and clear the prodSel variable
        if (prodSel == "") 
            {
                prodSel = a;
            }else 
            {
            if (prodSel != a)
                {
                alert ( "Please ensure that the groups are same for the items you select");
                //alert(b);
                document.getElementById(b).checked  = false;
                }
            }

}

function ClearAllSelections()
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    var cbs = []; 
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
            {  
                if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") 
                    {  
                        inputs[i].checked = false;
                    }  
            }  
prodSel=""; // Clear the  variable; allow new selections
}

/*loop through and if all of them are unchecke,d clear the variable*/
function ClearAllSelectionsA()
{
var clre = true;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    var cbs = []; 
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
            {  
                if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") 
                    {  
                        if (inputs[i].checked){clre= false;}
                    }  
            }  
            if (clre){
prodSel=""; // Clear the  variable; allow new selections
alert(window.prodSel);
}
}
</script>
<body>


G1<input type="checkbox" value="zxc" id="12" onclick="javascript:VerifyGroup('g1',12);"><BR>
G1<input type="checkbox" value="zxcw" id="123" onclick="javascript:VerifyGroup('g1',123);"><BR>
G1<input type="checkbox" value="zxcdw" id="124" onclick="javascript:VerifyGroup('g1',124);"><BR>
G2<input type="checkbox" value="zxcf" id="125" onclick="javascript:VerifyGroup('g2',125);"><BR>
G2<input type="checkbox" value="zxcfg" id="126" onclick="javascript:VerifyGroup('g2',126);"><BR>
<a href="#" onclick="ClearAllSelections();">clear group</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, we now know what you want. Is the code you posted doing that?  If not, what is working differently than you thought?

Comment: No, the code fails to clear grouping upon the last uncheck. So the call to function ClearAllSelectionsA fails to reset the variable to "". hence i have to manually include a clear function.

Comment: I think it might have something to do with all your id's being numeric. Try putting a letter in front of all your id's, and passing the new string as the second parameter to `VerifyGroup`. [The id attribute must contain a letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/79022#79022)

Comment: @johnhopkins : have tried that and no luck.

Comment: `language="javascript"` is deprecated use `type="text/javascript"` instead. You should try to avoid global variables - or if it isn't avoidable - use namespacing or an immediately self executed function to minimize the "pollution" of the global namespace

Comment: @Andreas : Changed it. Thanks for suggestion but that did not work either.

Comment: When you call `ClearAllSelectionsA`, if all the checkboxes are unchecked, then `prodSel` gets cleared. Then back in `VerifyGroup`, `prodSel` is immediately being reassigned to `a`

Comment: @johnhopkins : you might have caught it. let me check your suggestion.

Comment: @johnhopkins - thank you. thank you all who looked at it. it solves the problem :D

Comment: You're welcome, schar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `ClearAllSelectionsA`, if all the checkboxes are unchecked, then `prodSel` gets cleared. Then back in `VerifyGroup`, `prodSel` is immediately being reassigned to `a`. My recommendation would be to return true or false from `ClearAllSelectionsA` and act based upon that value.

```
<script language="javascript">
var prodSel="";
function VerifyGroup(a,b)
{
    var cleared = ClearAllSelectionsA(); // check if this is the last unselect and clear the prodSel variable
    if (prodSel == "" && !cleared) //only reset prodSel if there is a checkbox checked
    {
        prodSel = a;
    }else 
    {
        if (prodSel != a)
        {
            alert ( "Please ensure that the groups are same for the items you select");
            //alert(b);
            document.getElementById(b).checked  = false;
        }
    }
}

function ClearAllSelections()
{
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    var cbs = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
    {
        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") 
        {
            inputs[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
    prodSel=""; // Clear the  variable; allow new selections
}

/*loop through and if all of them are unchecke,d clear the variable*/
function ClearAllSelectionsA()
{
    var clre = true;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); 
    var cbs = []; 
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
        {  
            if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") 
            {  
                if (inputs[i].checked){clre= false;}
            }  
        }  
        if (clre){
             prodSel=""; // Clear the  variable; allow new selections
             alert(window.prodSel);
        }
        return clre;
    }
</script>
```